# Inference rules for quantifiers in natural deduction - are all the conditions correct?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Because I am getting quite confused with the definition of the four inference rules for quantifiers, and all of their conditions, I would like to write them down here as I understand it.  My questions follow afterwards:

---

**Preliminaries**

The substitution $\phi[t/x]$ represents the formula $\phi$ after all *free* variables $x$ are replaced in $\phi$ with the term $t$.  The term $t$ can be a constant, variable or function expression, but $x$ must be a variable

The term $t$ is said to be *substitutable* if when performing the substitution $\phi[t/x]$, no variables within $t$ become bound by any quantifier within $\phi$.

---

**Universal elimination**

If $\Gamma \vdash \forall x\, \phi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \phi[t/x]$.

*Restrictions*:

- $t$ can be any term (constant, variable or function expression) that must be substitutable for $x$ within $\phi$.

---

**Existential introduction**

If $\Gamma \vdash \phi[t/x]$, then $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \, \phi$.

*Restrictions*:

- $t$ can be any term (constant, variable or function expression) that must be substitutable for $x$ within $\phi$.

---

**Universal introduction**

If $\Gamma \vdash \phi[t/x]$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \, \phi$.

*Restrictions*:

- $t$ can be any term (constant, variable or function expression) that must be substitutable for $x$ within $\phi$
- $t$ cannot be present in any formula within $\Gamma$.

---

**Existential elimination**

If $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \,\phi$ and $\Gamma, \phi[t/x] \vdash \psi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \psi$.

*Restrictions*:

- $t$ can be any term (constant, variable or function expression) that must be substitutable for $x$ within $\phi$
- $t$ can not be present in $\phi$
- $t$ cannot be present in $\psi$
- $t$ cannot be present in any formulas within $\Gamma$.

---

My questions then, are:

- Are these rules correct and complete?  Are any restrictions missing, unnecessary, or are there any restrictions that are *too* restrictive?
- I'm particularly suspect about the conditions on $\forall I$ and $\exists E$, which state that "$t$ cannot be present in any formulas within $\Gamma~$".  I feel like this can be relaxed to "$t$ cannot be *free* in any formulas within $\Gamma~$".  Or am I wrong?  For instance, shouldn't you be able to derive the following sequent: $\forall x \, Px \vdash \forall x(x = 0 \vee \forall x \, Px)$, which would not be possible with the restrictions as they stand.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$
$$\fitch {
   1. \qquad \forall x Px \qquad (A)
}{
   2. \qquad x = 0 \vee \forall x Px \qquad (\vee I) \\
   3. \qquad \forall x(x = 0 \vee \forall x Px) \qquad (\forall I: )
}
$$

- The definition for substitution in Chiswell and Hodges *Mathematical Logic* seems to require that a term $t$ be substitutable for *any* substitution (Definition 7.27 pg. 167).  That is, $t$ being substitutable is implied in any substitution.  Therefore, I think I could embed the concept of substitutability within the definition of substitution itself, and can remove the first restriction from each of these inference rules.  However, others have said that the two concepts are independent.  That is, a substitution can occur without a term being substitutable.  This seems strange to me; indeed Chiswell and Hodges say that such a substitution is "meaningless"(p. 183) and "undefined" (p. 167).

Comment: Correct: in ∀I the variable $x$ may not occur *free* in any hypothesis on which $ϕ(x)$ depends.

Comment: As you can see from page 110, C&H follows a "reverse" approach: they first define *sustitutable for* (or *free for*) in Def.5.2.9 and then they define the opertion of *substitution* in term of the previous one (Def.5.2.10). In this way, substitutions are preformed only if the "substitutability" condition holds.

Comment: You must take into account that C&H use a *term* $t$ in the statement of the rule. $t$ can be a variable $y$, a *constant* $c$ or a "complex" term like $f(x)$ of $f(c)$. Only variables may be quantified and we do not quantify constants and "complex" terms. Thus, tehy cannot write: "$t$ *free*".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so with respect to the $\forall I$ rule, the restrictions should be as written above in general for terms $t$, but if $t$ is just a variable, then there can be some relaxation of the rules; that is, $t$ can occur in $\Gamma$, but it just must not be free.

Comment: Correct; your derivation above is sound. So, if the rule is expressed only withrespect to variables, the restriction is: "$x$ does not occur *free*". If the rule is expressed for *terms*, you have to manage the different cases.

Comment: For a different approach to ND rules, you can see [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA90), page 90: $\forall$E rule is expressed in terms of free var $x$, and then the following theorem is proved by induction: "If $c$ [a constant] does not occur in $\Gamma$, then: if $\Gamma \vdash ϕ(c)$, then $\Gamma \vdash ∀xϕ(x)$."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks I'll take a look at that.  It concerns me that C&H's construction of the inference rules exclude derivations that are sound.

Comment: I do not agree; the derivation can be simply written as follows: $\forall x Px \vdash y=0 \lor \forall x Px \vdash \forall x (x=0 \lor \forall x Px)$.

Comment: In universal Introduction shouldn't there be a further restriction that $t$ does not occur in $\phi$? Otherwise let $t=0$ and $\phi \equiv x=0$. Then $\phi[t/x] \equiv 0=0$ and the rule allows us from $\Gamma \vdash 0=0$ derive $\Gamma \vdash \forall x (x=0)$.

Comment: $\phi [t/x] \equiv t = 0$.  And you've introduced an assumption that $t = 0$ which has not been discharged.